# imacros take from multi files in DATASOURCE loop

Tags: imacros

I have imacros firefox Add-ons that takes data from one csv file. But i need to tell imacros to take data from multi files as loop
 here my script is take from 1.csv 
 but I've 2.csv & 3.csv & 4.csv and more.. i need it to take from them as loop like if i run play imacros will take data from 1.csv once they finish start again but from 2.csv ..etc like that.. with the same rule for all.. also the files all are the same columns same data but cannot merge them as one file.csv

```
SET !DATASOURCE /Users/almishal/Desktop/imacros/new/1.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 18
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.example.com/vb/sty1/buttons/newthread.gif
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:vbform ATTR=NAME:subject CONTENT={{!COL2}}
SET !VAR1 EVAL("'{{!COL4}}'.replace(/^965/gi,"")")
SET PRICE {{!COL5}}
SET !VAR3 EVAL("'price:<SP>{{PRICE}}<SP>dollar'.replace(/price:<SP>0+<SP>dollar/,"")")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:vbform ATTR=ID:vB_Editor_001_textarea CONTENT=[CENTER]{{!COL3}}<BR>{{!VAR3}}<BR><SP>my<SP>number<SP>{{!VAR1}}<SP><BR><BR>{{!VAR2}}<BR>[/CENTER]
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:vbform ATTR=ID:vB_Editor_001_save
TAG POS=1 TYPE=AREA ATTR=HREF:http://www.example.com/vb/index.php
ONDIALOG POS=1 BUTTON=OK CONTENT=
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:log<SP>out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most elegant solution with the help of [the JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface). But here I suggest a one using only ‘iim’s. So, create e.g. ‘macro1.iim’ for ‘1.csv’, ‘macro2.iim’ for ‘2.csv’ etc. The code of the ‘macro1.iim’ will be as follows:

```
' number of lines in csv-files
SET linesInFile 1
SET !LOOP EVAL(2-{{linesInFile}})
SET !DATASOURCE /Users/almishal/Desktop/imacros/new/1.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE EVAL({{!LOOP}}+{{linesInFile}}-1)
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
' ... (your code here)

' next macro to play
SET next "macro2"
SET S EVAL("('{{!LOOP}}' == 1) ? 'imacros://run/?m={{next}}.iim' : 'javascript:undefined;';")
URL GOTO={{S}}
```

I believe that you’ve caught the idea and will make necessary corrections to ‘macro2.iim’ etc. (There won’t be a ‘next macro to play’ block in the last macro.) In order to play this chain you should run only ‘macro1.iim’ in usual (NOT loop) mode. Also note that I supposed that all macros are in the root of the default ‘iMacros’ folder for them.