# Restart iMacros from the beginning

Tags: imacros, restart

i want to restart my iMacros from the beginning, without using java.

So for example:

```
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
WAIT SECONDS=1
RESTART <----NOT EXISTING
```

Is there some way? Or maybe a workaround to do:

```
WAIT SECONDS=1
URL GOTO=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
WAIT SECONDS=1
GOTO LINE=1 <----NOT EXISTING
```

Comment: Just play your macro in loop mode.

Comment: Its because when i recieve and error, i want to start from the beginning.
I dont want to !ERRORIGNORE YES

Comment: You need to apply `if`-statement and therefore [the JavaScript Scripting Interface for Firefox](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface). However you can try to follow some ideas given in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755180/imacros-take-from-multi-files-in-datasource-loop) .

Comment: THANK YOU !!! Exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by Shugar:

```
SET next "MacroNameToRestart"
SET S EVAL("('{{!LOOP}}' == 1) ? 'imacros://run/?m={{next}}.iim' : 'javascript:undefined;';")
URL GOTO={{S}}
```